# Convert NA to any type, including POSIXct

Tags: r, class, na

I would like to insert NAs in a variable that has the same type as the a variable. So for a variable `x` that can have any class, I would like to generate NAs of the same class. `as(NA, class(x))` works great for everything but `POSIXct`:

```r
> x = as.POSIXct("2021-01-01")
> as(NA, class(x))
Error in class1Def@contains[[class2]] : no such index at level 1
```

The same is true for:

```r
> x_na = NA
> class(x_na) = class(x)
> identical(x_na, lubridate::NA_POSIXct_)
FALSE
```

The broader context: I'm trying to set all but some columns to NA for particular rows in a user-provided data.frame that can have any number of columns of any type. So the NAs should be of the same type.. Using

```r
  mutate(df, across(
    -c(except, these, columns), 
    ~ if_else(some_col == "some_value", as(NA, class(.)), .)
  ))
```

works great except for the above error for `POSIXct` columns. Is there another way?

Comment: You can try `as.POSIXct(NA)`

Comment: @RonakShah That would give wrong types if x is `numeric` or another type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an unsatisfactory workaround, this hard-coded replacement for `POSIXct` vars works:

```r
classed_na = function(x) {
  if (is.POSIXct(x)) {
    lubridate::NA_POSIXct_
  } else {
    as(NA, class(x))
  }
}
```

Use like

```r
mutate(df, across(
    -c(except, these, columns), 
    ~ if_else(some_col == "some_value", classed_na(.), .)
  ))
```